# Is it possible and relatively easy to boot a 2013 MacBook Air from an external drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, startup, external-disk

Given a MacBook Air that's working but with dead display and SSD, can I use it as a desktop-only machine with an external monitor and external hard drive?

The guy at the Apple Store Genius Bar this afternoon told me I could install the OS on an external drive and boot from it, but I'm sure even Apple Geniuses sometimes make wrong assumptions?

If it is possible would a USB external drive suffice or would it require a drive that connects to the proprietary connector?

Also if it is possible, is it fairly straightforward?

(I am a technical/computer guy, but not a Mac guy.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work, depending on the model of MacBook Air an external USB drive **will** be able to boot the system but it will likely be slower than an internal drive on the PCI/SATA bus. You should also have a Thunderbolt or mini display port for connecting a monitor.

So it *should* work. Whether or not it will perform acceptably is difficult to say.

Comment: Yep it works great. Fast enough for me.